# What's the best way to execute something only when all my JavaScript is loaded using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript

I'm developing a web page using jQuery, and I want it to execute some code only after ALL my JavaScript files are fully loaded. The `head` section of my HTML has the following script.

```
<script src="supervisor/lib/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Inside jQuery file, I inserted the following code:

```
$.getScript('functions.js', function () {
  // code here
});
```

The file functions.js has the following code:

```
$.getScript('mask.js');
$.getScript('validations.js');
$.getScript('lotsofscripts.js');
// and more...
```

I want the *code here* in the first `$.getScript()` to execute only after ALL the other JS are loaded, but this is not ocurring. What's the best way to achieve this?

PS: I'm using lots of `$.getScript()` because I find easier to separate them, but I want them to be inserted inside the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just increment a counter. That way your getScript calls remain asynchronous, as the *last* thing you want to do is change that. And frankly, any packaged solution you find to loading the scripts in parallel and then executing some function afterward will probably just be a shinier version of this:

```
var counter = 0;
var filesToLoad = ["mask.js", "validations.js", "lotsofscripts.js"];
var filesCount = filesToLoad.length;

// Increment counter each time a getScript completes
function incrementCounter() {
  if (++counter === filesCount) {
    // This code will execute after everything loads
  }
}

// Iterate through the files and run getScript on them,
// with incrementCounter as the callback
for (var i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
  $.getScript(filesToLoad[i], incrementCounter);
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tDRNp/).

Comment: I was typing up my own version of this but yours is simpler and better.  +1

Comment: getScript fires the success callback after the script is *loaded*, but not necessarily after it is *executed*. That callback is not a reliable signal that the contents of the script are ready for use. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/#success-callback

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the name of a function defined in a js script that needs to be tested for whether or not it has loaded...

I use Underscore.js isFunction() to figure this out ( http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isFunction )

Example, if script.js contains a function myScriptFunction(), you can write a function that checks:

```
if (_.isFunction(myScriptFunction)) {
  // script.js is loaded
  // OK to move on to the next step
} else {
  // script.js is not loaded
  // check again later
}
```

I have tried binding to events to figure out if a js script file is loaded, but it doesn't seem to work across all the browsers.

Comment: You can also use typeof and check that the type is "function", so like:  if typeof somefunc_in_included_script == "function" { // doSomething }

Comment: I was looking for something less specific. There are lots of `$.getScript()`. and the scripts they're loading are constantly being modified (read inserting functions, etc). I just wanted the code to load only after all the external javascript are loaded, no matter the functions inside them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/) to load your JS files. You can execute specific code upon completion of specific files or groups of files. Take a look, it's a great little project.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead. You can set the async option to false (it's true by default when you use getScript